# Integration of $\sin^{-1} (x)$ using Lagrange notation

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, notation

I would like to find the anti-derivative of $\sin^{-1} (x)$ using Lagrange notation.
For derivation, Lagrange uses $f'(x)$, $f''(x)$, etc. However, for anti-derivation he uses $\int$ (elongated $S$) symbol and $f(x)$ in it.

We would like to compute the derivative of $\sin^{-1} (x)$. Let $y = \sin^{-1} (x)$. Here $y$ is the function of $x$, so $f(x) = \sin^{-1}  (x)$. Now, $\sin (y) = x$. then, we can also write it as $\sin [f(x)] = x$, since $y = f(x)$.

Then, differentiating using the chain rule,
$$\cos[f(x)] f'(x) = 1.$$
$$f'(x) = 1/\cos[f(x)].$$

Using trigonometry, $$\sin^2 [f(x)] + \cos^2 [f(x)] = 1,$$ $$\cos[f(x)] = \sqrt{ 1 - \sin^2[f(x)] }.$$ Which is equivalent to $\sqrt{1 - x^2}$.

So $f'(x) = 1 / \sqrt{1 - x^2}$.

Here $f'(x)$ means the derivative of function of $x$ w.r.t $x$, and $y$ is a function of $x$.
So by Leibniz notation, we can also write $dy/dx = f'(x)$, here $dy/dx$ also means the derivative of a function of $x$ w.r.t $x$ since $y$ is a function of $x$.

Similarly, how can I find the anti-derivative of $\sin^{-1} (x)$ using Lagrange notation, using as few symbols as possible; I don't want to treat $dy/dx$ like a ratio.

Comment: Use MathJax formatting

Comment: @Regretme Please learn how to use MathJax properly. I did it for you this time.

Comment: Hi Regretme. To compute $\int \arcsin(x) \, dx$, you make the substitution $u=\arcsin(x)$. I don't fully understand what you mean by "find the antiderivative of $\sin^{-1}(x)$ using Lagrange notation"—the notation doesn't affect what the answer to the integral is. If your concern is that making a substitution seems to treat $du/dx$ as a ratio, then you do not need to worry: this method works because of the substitution formula:
$$
\int f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \, dx = \int f'(u) \, du \Bigg|_{u=g(x)} \, .
$$
I can elaborate on how this method works, if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following method is equivalent to making the substitution $u=\arcsin(x)$, but it avoids treating $du/dx$ as a ratio. Notice that
$$
\int \arcsin(x) \, dx = \int \color{red}{\arcsin(x) \cdot \sqrt{1-\sin^2(\arcsin(x))}} \cdot \color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}} \, dx \, .
$$
This integral is of the form
$$
\int \color{red}{f'(g(x))} \cdot \color{blue}{g'(x)} \, dx \, ,
$$
with $f'(u)=u\cdot\sqrt{1-\sin^2(u)}$ and $g(x)=\arcsin(x)$. Since
$$
\int f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \, dx =f(g(x))+C \, ,
$$
we get that
$$
\int \arcsin(x) \cdot \sqrt{1-\sin^2(\arcsin(x))} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx = f(\arcsin (x)) \, ,
$$
where $f$ is an antiderivative of $u \cdot \sqrt{1-\sin^2(u)}$. So the problem reduces to integrating $u\cdot\sqrt{1-\sin^2(u)}$, which we can doing using integration by parts:
\begin{align}
\int u \cdot \sqrt{1-\sin^2(u)} &= \int u \cos(u) \, du \\[4pt]
&= u\sin(u)-\int \sin(u) \, du\\[4pt]
&= u\sin(u)+\cos(u) + C \, .
\end{align}
Hence, $f(u)=u\sin(u)+\cos(u)+C$, and so
\begin{align}
\int \arcsin(x) \, dx &= \arcsin(x)\sin(\arcsin(x)) + \cos(\arcsin(x)) + C \\[4pt]
&= x\arcsin(x) + \sqrt{1-x^2} + C \, .
\end{align}

Comment: can you elaborate how $f'(u) = u. sqrt(1 -sin^2 (u))$ ?

Comment: instead of $f'(u) = 1/sqrt(1 - sin^2 (u))$

Comment: @Regretme: I'm defining $f'(u)$ as $u \cdot \sqrt{1-\sin^2(u)}$ and $g(x)$ as $\arcsin(x)$ so that we can say the integral is of the form $\int f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \, dx$. Does that help?

Comment: @Regretme: I don't understand what you mean, sorry. Could you elaborate please? Are you asking how I came up with this solution to the problem?

Comment: yes, how you came up with that solution, like how you identified the form 
$f'(g(x)). g'(x)$ from the initial form $arcsin(x)$

Comment: @Regretme: If you are trying to integrate $\phi(g(x))$, then provided that $g$ is one-to-one, we can rewrite the integral in the following way:
$$
\int \phi(g(x)) \, dx = \int \frac{\phi(g(x))}{g'(x)} \cdot g'(x) = \int \frac{\phi(g(x))}{g'(g^{-1}(g(x)))} \cdot g'(x) \, dx
$$
By setting $\displaystyle{f'(u)=\frac{\phi(u)}{g'(g^{-1}(u))}}$, we can write the integral as
$$
\int f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \, dx = f(g(x)) + C \, .
$$

Comment: @Regretme: In this case, we are integrating $\arcsin(x)$, where $\phi(u)=u$ and $g(x)=\arcsin(x)$. I knew to multiply the top and bottom by $g'(x)$ because I have looked into the theory behind integration by substitution. I would highly recommend reading Michael Spivak's *Calculus* (see, in particular, Chapter 19—Integration in Elementary Terms).